# How can I search for 3 strings at a time in the vi editor?

Tags: linux, unix, vi

How can I search for 3 strings at a time in the vi editor?

I was wondering how could we do it. I.e. search for 3 strings at a time in [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)
like I do: `:/xyz` in command mode.

How could I add 2 more strings so that the cursor will stop at a string which ever is found first among the three and if we press `n` it will stop at the string that is found second among the three?

I suppose this would be very helpful in real time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the bar (`|`), escaped (i.e., with a backslash in front, so that it is not interpreted as a literal bar):

```
/string1\|string2\|string3
```

Note that the colon (`:`) is not necessary. In command mode, you can just type a slash (`/`); no need to type a colon first.

Comment: Strange that you have to escape the pipe symbol, which is the opposite from standard RegExp. $-)

Comment: @SanHolo: yes. This holds for e.g. parentheses and square brackets as well. I suppose the philosophy behind this is that most users will use the search functionality for "regular" (non-regexp) searches.

Comment: See `:help magic` for more details on when you should escape special characters, and how you can change this.